# how to get friends list in php?

Tags: php, mysql

my sql query 
    i am using this type of query i am getting friends like who sent friend rquest for me and accepted by me.but i did not get friends when i  sent friend request for friends and accepted by friend

My tables are as so

```
First table 'user_details'
id
firstname
lastname
username

second table 'friendslist'
sno
userid
friendid
status (1 for friend)


$id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $query="select * from friendslist f INNER JOIN user_details u on f.userid=u.id where f.status='1' AND  f.friendid='$id'";

    $select=mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($select)>0){
        while($result_temp=mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
        $resultnewfriend[]=$result_temp;
        }
    }else{
        $resultnewfriend=array();
    }   
    return $resultnewfriend;
```

Comment: Sorry, what you need?

Comment: firstly i didnt get your question ..secondly i think you are mising some more info

Comment: You need to create another query or a `UNION` where the `f.userid=$id`

Answer (score 0):

according to your question you want to get current user friend list

```
"select * from friendlist where user_id=$id"
```